# Automating Sequence of Manual Steps

Tags: automation, workflow, activiti

I have sequence of steps that an user does, e.g. logging on the a remote UNIX shell, creation of files/directories, changing permission, Running remote Shell scripts and commands, File deletion, File movements,

Run DB queries and basis the query results perform certain tasks exporting the results to a file or run further shell commands/scripts or DB insert statements etc etc.

doing there steps users achieves different processed or data processing and validating.

What is the best way to automate the above schenerio, Should we go for a Workflow tools like Activiti etc. or is there a better framework/way to achieve the requirements.

My requirement is to work with Open-source, and possibly Java based.

I am completely new to this so any help pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you already done some research (aka googling) on job scheduling tools ? There are plenty of those that would fit your requirements. Activiti can sure be used for that, but my feeling is that would require more work   when compared to those tools.

Comment: My requirement is more towards create a workflow, or sequence of steps done manually today into a automated system. Wherein some of the steps also involves user input or verification before the next one gets triggered. I am not sure if job scheduling would be sufficient for my requirement.  User currently Does all the steps manually which includes preparing the system, executing the process by doing sequence of steps like logging into a remote UNIX server, Executing Quires and basis the results do some more actions. and then proceed to  the next process in line.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you describe is certainly possible with a workflow tool like Activiti. Apache Camel or Spring Integration would be another possibility (as all the steps you mention are automatic system tasks).

A workflow framework would be a good option if you need one of these

- you want to store the history data for 'audit purposes': who did what/when/how long did it take.
- you want to visually model your steps, perhaps to discuss it with business people.
- there is a need for human interaction between some of the steps

Comment: My requirement is to decide a framework that we can use to automate the steps done manually at the moment. And some of the steps would require human interaction in between and user should be able to get a visual model as to where the process has reached at the moment. I am trying to look at Activiti but could not make much sense as to how i can use that. Most of my steps are related to running some shell scripts on a remote UNIX system. I am not sure if activiti has a visual representation of the running processes. all i can figure out is i can expose REST API to perform some steps.

Answer (score 0):

Your description reminds me of a software/account provisioning process.
There are a large number of provisioning tools on the market both Open Source or otherwise (Dell Crowbar is one options).
However, A couple of the comments you made in your response to Joram indicate a more general purpose tool such as Activiti may be an option:

1. "Swivel Chair" tasks - User tasks that may one day be automated
2. Visual model of process state

Most provisioning tools dont allow for generic user tasks and dont provide a (good) visual model of the process state.
However, they generally include remote script execution which would need to be cobbled together as a service task if using a BOM tool.

I would certainly expand my research to include provisioning tools as they sound like a better fit, however if you cant find anything that works for you, a BPM platform provides a generic framework to build what you need.

Comment: Thanks, The above steps are more targeted towards validating the system, Whether all the configurations and DB entries are correct and the different processes that ran, were successful and correctly updated various DB's and all the log files were generated and have relevant entries. To do that validation user logs onto a various systems and Databases and done some sequence of steps.